# What all information we can pass as parameters to inline event handlers?

Tags: javascript, html

I found this code on internet where author is passing `id` of the element as first parameter to the event handler. Refer to the sample below.

Until today, I was under the impression that we can pass only `event` information as argument to the event handler and I can see that we can pass `id` of current element also as parameter to event handler.

Where is this documented on MDN? Can someone point to me the documentation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="Hello" onchange="someFunction(id,event);" id="someId"/>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function someFunction(id,event){
            console.log(id); //Printing "someId"
            console.log(event.target.value); //It is printing updated value 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get id as `event.target.id` but I am curious as where is it documented that we can pass `Id` of element also?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can refer to any property that's somewhere in the element's prototype chain as a standalone variable:

```js
function someFunction(id, onclick, children, clientTop) {
  console.log(id);        // someId
  console.log(onclick);   // note, this is null, not undefined!
  console.log(children);  // length 0, but still an HTMLCollection
  console.log(clientTop); // 2
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello" onchange="someFunction(id, onclick, children, clientTop);" id="someId" />
```

It's as if the inline handler is wrapped in a `with(this)`. Referencing a property name that exists on the element object, or in the element's prototype chain, will result in that property value being referenced.

So, an inline handler like

```
<input onchange="somestr">
```

is interpreted something like

```
// assume this refers to that input element:
with (this) {
  eval(somestr);
}
```

Note that `event` is in a different category - it's not a property of the element, it's a global `window.event`.